# Swift draw image asset on an image

Tags: ios, swift, uigraphicscontext

I'm trying to draw an image asset called GreyCircle (small grey circle, 25x25) onto an image in Swift 4, but I can't seem to get it right. By the way, this is in a tap-gesture function, that is, I'm trying to draw the grey circle where the user taps on a photo. `displayedImage` holds the current image being displayed.

Code:

```
self.touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self.view)
let greyCircle = UIImage(named: "GreyCircle")   

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(displayedImage.size, false, 0.0)
displayedImage.draw(in: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:displayedImage.size.width, height: displayedImage.size.height))
greyCircle.draw(in: CGRect(x:touchPoint.x, y:touchPoint.y, width:displayedImage.size.width, height: displayedImage.size.height))
let newImag = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
displayedImage = newImag
```

The `greyCircle.draw` line is not correct, but it's my latest attempt.  I'm sure I'm missing something bone-headed.

Comment: Why you draw the greyCircle with displayImage's size?

Answer (score 1):

You want to translate the touch point to the bounds of the image view. Then when drawing the circle, use the circle's size, not the image's size.

```
let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: displayedImage)
let greyCircle = UIImage(named: "GreyCircle")   

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(displayedImage.size, false, 0.0)
displayedImage.draw(in: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:displayedImage.size.width, height: displayedImage.size.height))
greyCircle.draw(in: CGRect(x:touchPoint.x, y:touchPoint.y, width: greyCircle.size.width, height: greyCircle.size.height))
let newImag = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
displayedImage = newImag
```

Comment: When I try to do "let touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.location(in: displayedImage)" I get the red-exclamation error, "Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage!' to expected argument type 'UIView?'.

Comment: Oh. I mistakenly thought `displayedImage` what an image view. Do you have an image view? replace `displayedImage` on that line with your image view.

Comment: My bad for not clarifying that. So taggedImage is what I am trying now, and that is a UIImageView IBOutlet, that extends to the bounds of the ViewController it is in. When the user goes to this VC, they see the photo encompassing the entire screen. When they tap, I want the image asset GreyCircle to be drawn where they tap (effectively tagging the image). So I replaced taggedImage where I had displayedImage and it's still not working. Thanks so much for any further insight you may have. FYI, I did this successfully drawing text labels, but I can't get his darn grey circle to draw.

Comment: The grey circle is not being drawn on the image. I know that the tap is happening because I am logging that to the console.

Comment: Confirm the value of `touchPoint` and `greyCircle`. Use the debugger. See what's happening.

Comment: Any luck with the investigating?

Comment: Circle turned out to not be a problem, and then I had to back-burner for higher priorities.  I'll post once I return to it and get it working.